# How to access a column whose name is stored in a variable?

Tags: oracle

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1
AS
  MYCOLUMNVAR  VARCHAR2(50);

BEGIN
SELECT <<some query>> INTO MYCOLUMNVAR FROM DUAL;    --this query contains 
                                                     -- a regular expression 
                                                     -- and some other criteria 
                                                     -- to store a column
                                                     -- name into MYCOLUMNVAR


INSERT INTO TABLE_TMP(ID,COLUMN1)
       (SELECT a.ID,b.MYCOLUMNVAR FROM TAB1 a, TAB2 b WHERE...)
```

the value assigned to `MYCOLUMNVAR` from the above query is `DATA`. I have a column name `DATA` in the table `TAB2`. While trying to run the procedure I am getting

```
Error(50,3): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "B"."MYCOLUMNVAR": invalid identifier.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [dynamic query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm) to solve that kind of issue:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO TABLE_TMP(ID,COLUMN1)
            (SELECT a.ID,b.' || MYCOLUMNVAR || ' FROM TAB1 a, TAB2 b WHERE...)'
```